# Mapping query string to object with AutoMapper

Tags: query-string, automapper, httpcontext

I have discovered AutoMapper recently, and I´m thinking if I could mapping `HttpConext`, (really query parameters) to a typed object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HttpRequest.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) is a NameValueCollection. So you could create some custom mapping for this like in the example [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2010/05/09/automapper-mappingfunction-from-source-type-of-namevaluecollection.aspx).